# Unable to Inject Mock Object - ActivityUnitTestCase

Tags: android, mockito, activityunittestcase

I've been trying to test a sample app using Mockito.

My test case:

```
public class CalcActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<CalcActivity> {

private Intent in;
private Button btnAdd,btnSub,btnMul,btnDiv,btnDef;
private TextView res;
private CalcActivity mActivity;
@Mock
private Vars mockVar;


public CalcActivityTest() {
    super(CalcActivity.class);
}

@Before
protected void setUp() throws Exception{

    super.setUp();

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(mockVar.getn1()).thenReturn(20.0);
    when(mockVar.getn2()).thenReturn(40.0);

    in = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),CalcActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("num1", 20.0);
    in.putExtra("num2",20.0);
    startActivity(in, null, null);
}
@UiThreadTest
public void testOperations(){

    mActivity = getActivity();

    btnAdd = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.advancedcalc.R.id.add);
    btnSub = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.advancedcalc.R.id.sub);
    btnMul = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.advancedcalc.R.id.mul);
    btnDiv = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.advancedcalc.R.id.div);

    btnDef = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.advancedcalc.R.id.btnDef);
    res = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.advancedcalc.R.id.res);
    btnAdd.performClick();

    assertEquals(40.0 , Double.parseDouble(res.getText().toString()));

    btnSub.performClick();
    assertEquals(0.0 , Double.parseDouble(res.getText().toString()));

    btnMul.performClick();
    assertEquals(400.0, Double.parseDouble(res.getText().toString()));

    btnDiv.performClick();
    assertEquals(1.0 , Double.parseDouble(res.getText().toString()));

    btnDef.performClick();
    btnAdd.performClick();
    assertEquals(1000 , Double.parseDouble(res.getText().toString()));

}
}
```

**Vars** is a class that passes some default variables into the **CalcActivity**.

My problem is that, the variable mockVar is never used. All calls from CalcActivity goes to the Vars class that is originally present in the CalcActivty.

Can anyone point what i'm doing wrong regarding mockVar injection ?

Comment: Just FYI, the documentation on ActivityUnitTestCase says never to call startActivity inside setup.  You're supposed to call it in the test method itself.

Answer (score 0):

- I think you have missed -

  `@InjectMocks
  private CalcActivity mActivity;`
- Are you using "new" for creating new object of Vars? Not sure but, I think there should be having some setter injection like [ Need experts advise here ] -

  `public void setVars(Vars vars){
  this.vars = vars;
  }`

And then inject your mock object using this method.

```
mActivity.setVars(mockVar);
```

- Then call the method after you stubbed everything like -

  `mActivity.callYourMethodWhichYouAreTesting();`

Comment: How is `@InjectMocks` going to help?  You'd create a `CalcActivity`, inject the mock, then assign `mActivity` to something else.  The rest of your answer makes some sense, but to know how best to inject `mockVar` into the system under test, we'd really need to know more about what's going on inside `Intent` and `CalcActivity`.